# Why is methyl α-D-glucopyranoside preferentially formed from glucopyranose in acidic methanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates, stereoelectronics

According to my textbook Organic Chemistry 2e by David Klein, the formation of a glycoside from glucopyranose favors the α form (see picture below).

Why does this happen? Shouldn't the equilibrium favor the β form, where the methoxy group is in an equatorial position and has less steric interactions?

[image: picture]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, if there is overlap between a filled orbital and an unfilled orbital, a stabilising interaction will take place between the two. A simple example is the resonance present in esters, where the ester oxygen lone pair (a *filled* orbital) overlaps with the C=O π* orbital (an *unfilled* orbital):

[image: Resonance in an ester]

In this context, [*anomer*](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/A/A00373.html) refers to a diastereomer differing only in the configuration at C-1. So, the two diastereomeric products you have drawn above are often called the α and β anomers.

In the α anomer, there is one lone pair on the ring oxygen (a *filled* orbital) which can overlap with the C–OMe σ* orbital (an *unfilled* orbital):

[image: Anomeric effect in α anomer]

This leads to a stabilisation of roughly 6 to 7 kJ/mol, and is called the **anomeric effect**.

In the β anomer, neither of the two lone pairs on the ring oxygen overlap well with the C–OMe σ*.

[image: Poor orbital overlap in β anomer]

Of course, steric effects would disfavour the α anomer, which possesses an axial methoxy group. However, this factor only leads to a destabilisation of roughly 3 to 4 kJ/mol, and is therefore outweighed by the stereoelectronic stabilisation provided by the anomeric effect.

The rough numbers are taken from Kirby, A. J. *Stereoelectronic Effects* (OUP), p 16.

---

While the lone pair -> σ* explanation is the most commonly invoked, there are also likely to be other factors that are also present: for example, in the α anomer, the dipole moments of the ring oxygen lone pair and the exocyclic C–O bond oppose each other, which is a favourable electrostatic interaction:

[image: Dipole-dipole interactions in both anomers]

Comment: Good explanation of the anomeric effect. However, the question should also be ‘… and why is the methyl glucopyranoside different from simple D-glucose (which prefers beta in solution)?’

Comment: why is the anomeric effect not operative in case of glucose?

Comment: @Infinite That's a different question, ask it as a new question please; and I don't know the answer anyway.